# Why is Eve portrayed as manipulative and outright rude?

Tags: character, mother

In *Mother!* (2017), if I am not wrong Michelle Pfeiffer's character is supposed to be Eve. Why is she shown to be as she is in the movie? I didn't understand her motives and her interaction with "mother". She was bitchy and she was obviously portrayed to not be liked. What was the director trying to say here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Mother!* is essentially a sacrilegious allegory meant to portray humans as an unwanted houseguest.

The cast of characters are Him (God), Mother (mother nature), The Man (Adam), The Woman (Eve), their sons (Cain and Abel), other unwanted guests (mankind), the baby (Jesus), and the house (Earth).

Man is a very rude and intrusive house guest throughout the movie and is essentially the reason for the house being destroyed. Ultimately the message is basically about the conflict between man and mother nature, and how God always puts his love of man above his wife's (nature's) well-being. Thus allowing man to destroy the home and mother.

*Since man is the ultimate enemy in the film, it is fitting that Eve should be portrayed the way she was because Eve is the mother of mankind.*

Comment: This is possibly a slight oversimplification, but I think the point of Eve's portrayal was to set the precedent for the conflict between man and nature.